# Why are Bootstrap navbars rendered with different markup between Reactstrap and ASP React?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, reactstrap

I am writing a website with React, and using the reactstrap library
for some reasons, I create two React projects by visual studio 2022 templates, for the first one, I used **Standalone JavaScript React Template** , for the second one, I used **ASP.NET Core with React.js** ,

and in both project, I write the code like below

```
   <Navbar>
       <h2>Test</h2>
    </Navbar>
```

and I compare the html they rendered,

for the **Standalone JavaScript React Template**, the html looks like this, with a fluid box

```
<nav class="navbar"><div class="container-fluid"><h2>Test</h2></div></nav>
```

but for **ASP.NET Core with React.js** , the html looks like this, without a fluid box

```
<nav class="navbar"><h2>Test</h2></nav>
```

I tried to make them both at the most outside layer and remove all css file, they still different,

I am just curious about why same component will result different html in different project.

is there any setting those two different project causing this happen?

Thank you

Comment: Two different transpilers, or configurations?

Comment: Yeah, there's no rule that third parties have to implement Bootstrap in an identical fashion.